# Touch buttons in boostrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

in bootstrap we can define button groups and make the bigger buttons by setting a class called `btn-group-lg`:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

This mark up has this result:
[image]

I wonder If there's a way to make it like this:
[image]

Comment: You need to get out of class btn-group to be able to display them individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the btn-group btn-group-lg class. Use can edit this code according to your layout and needs.

```
<div class="col-md-1">  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
 <div class="col-md-1">  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
 <div class="col-md-1" style="clear:left">   
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
 <div class="col-md-1">  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Similar layout in medium size screen-->
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8"> 
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
  <div/>
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
  <div/>
 <div/>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
  <div/>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
  <div/>
 <div/>
<div/>
```